# Detecting accurate collision of two views in ios programming?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a "air hockey" type of game, I need to detect the collision of handle and puck in that. I am using the CGRectIntersectRect function for that but it is not accurate as when the frames from the edges collide, a collision is detected when the circles of puck and handle are not yet collided.

I hope I am making my point clear, so, any guidence on how I can achieve a more accurate collision of two circular images ?

Comment: The `CGRectIntersectRect()` function works perfectly. The error is in *your* code.

Comment: @H2CO3, So if a round object (one that appears round that is) intersects another rect at a 45 degree angle to the screen coordinate system, won't it return true prematurely (from a visual standpoint)? I assume that's the OP's concern.

Comment: @rdelmar Hm. I see what you mean. But then again, it's not the library function that's not working -- it's rather OP's expectation and/or maths knowledge is what's incorrect.

Comment: As H2CO3, suggests, you'll have to do some math if you want a more accurate answer. How complicated that math will be, depends on what your parameters are. What is "handle"? What shape is it, and (if not round) what is its angle to the screen? Is it fixed or variable?

Comment: @H2CO3 I know that CGRectIntersectRect() is perfect, the problem is that I have 2 circular images BUT their frames are rectengular, so, the collision from corner to corner will take at some distance from the actual collision of circles, I am asking for a alternative to CGRectIntersectRect() as I believe this function won't be able to solve this problem. If you think, I can change the question and add images to make it more clear ? Thanks

Comment: @divyenduz If you want to detect the distance of two circles, use Pythagoras' theorem: `d = sqrt((x2 - x1) ^ 2 + (y2 - y1) ^ 2)`, where x1, y1, x2 and y2 are the coordinates of the centers of the two circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the tip from @H2CO3, I implemented a function of my own that takes the center of circle 1 (x1,y1) and centre of circle 2 (x2,y2) and sum of radius of two circles (r) as parameters.

Calculates the distance between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), if the distance, say d, is less than r then the circles are intersecting.

Have a look at the implementation, works perfectly:

```
-(BOOL)WhenCircleDistanceIsLessThanRadiusX1:(int)x1 Y1:(int)y1 X2:(int)x2 Y2:(int)y2 R:(int)r
{
    int d = (int) sqrt(pow((x2-x1),2) + pow((y2-y1),2));
    return(d<=r);
}
```

Comment: `if (condition) return true; else return false;` is written more simply as `return condition;`

Comment: No, he meant this: `return (d <= r);`

Answer (score 0):

I'd give a shot to UIKit Dynamics collision detection engine. See example [here](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/3899-uikit-dynamics-and-ios-7-building-uikit-pong/).

Unfortunately it's iOS 7+, so if you plan to support iOS 6, you need to look for another solution.